# calling javascript class's method using this keyword in addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, events

I want to call the function getItemList() which is in a class 'Example' through addEventListener

```
var text_box = document.getElementById(this.text_box_id);
text_box.addEventListener('onchange', function(){this.getItemList('3', '10')}, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `change`, not `onchange`. Only in IE you have to use `on(EventName)`.

`this` inside the handler will refer to `text_box` (the element the event was raised on). You have to capture a reference to the current `this`:

```
var that = this;
text_box.addEventListener('change', function(){    
    that.getItemList('3', '10')
}, false);
```

Or in browsers supporting [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (you can also provide your own implementation as shown in this documentation):

```
text_box.addEventListener('change', function(){    
    this.getItemList('3', '10')
}.bind(this), false);
```