# Calling JavaScript class method using this keyword in addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to call the JavaScript class method using `addEventListener` with parameters using this keyword:

```
 var _this = this;
function onClickBound(e) {
    _this.getItemList.call(text_box, e || window.event);
}
if (text_box.addEventListener) {
    text_box.addEventListener("change", onClickBound, false);
}
```

Here it is working for without parameters, but I want with parameters i.e. I want to call `_this.getItemList('2','4')`.

The code is with reference to the

[stackoverflow addeventlistener this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/addeventlistener-this)

Comment: Did my answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242766/calling-javascript-classs-method-using-this-keyword-in-addeventlistener) not help? If not, why not? You can comment on every answer to your questions and give feedback. It looks to me that this is actually what you want to do. But if you don't give more information, it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `arguments` pseudo-argument within `onClickBound` to get at the runtime arguments that were passed, and then use `apply` to call `getItemList`.

Something like this (not tested):

```
var _this = this;
function onClickBound(e) {
    arguments[0] = e || window.event; // Handle IE-ism
    _this.getItemList.apply(text_box, arguments);
}
if (text_box.addEventListener) {
    text_box.addEventListener("change", onClickBound, false);
}
```

`arguments` is a pseudo-array that's predefined within every function and contains the arguments to the function. (It is *not* an `Array`, but it acts a lot like one and `apply` is happy to accept it.)

`apply` is the equivalent of `call`, but where you pass in an array-like-thing (`Array` or `arguments`) to specify the arguments, rather than supplying them as discrete args in the call.

---

**Update**: I think I may have misunderstood your question. Let's try that again:

If you want to "burn in" (curry) arguments into the function, you can use a function factory function (a function that creates functions) to do that:

```
if (text_box.addEventListener) {
    text_box.addEventListener(
        "change",
        createBoundEventHandler(this.getItemList, text_box, '2', '4'),
        false
    );
}
// Elsewhere with your other utility stuff
function createBoundEventHandler(f, thisArg) {
    var args, index;

    // Copy all but the first two args; leave a
    // gap at the beginning for the event argument
    args = [];
    for (index = 2; index < arguments.length; ++index) {
        args[index-1] = arguments[index];
    }

    // Return the function
    return function(e) {
        args[0] = e || window.event; // Handle IE-ism
        return f.apply(thisArg, args);
    };
}
```

That's a bit more complicated than the standard curry-style function would be, because we're leaving that gap at the beginning for the event argument.

If you don't want the event object (you did say at one point that you want to call `_this.getItemList('2','4')`), this should work:

```
if (text_box.addEventListener) {
    text_box.addEventListener(
        "change",
        bindAndCurry(this.getItemList, text_box, '2', '4'),
        false
    );
}
// Elsewhere with your other utility stuff
function bindAndCurry(f, thisArg) {
    var args, index;

    // Copy all but the first two args
    args = [];
    for (index = 2; index < arguments.length; ++index) {
        args.push(arguments[index]);
    }

    // Return the function
    return function() {
        return f.apply(thisArg, args);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this syntax for parametrised functions. [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for more details.

```js
var _this = this;
function onClickBound(e) {
    _this.getItemList.call(text_box, e || window.event);
}
if (text_box.addEventListener) {
    text_box.addEventListener("change", function(){onClickBound("x")}, false);
}
```